# Tengo problemas en modificar formulario en distintos archivos ¿cómo lo soluciono?

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3, formularios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo un problema en css espeficamente en dos archivos distinto  en mi estilo Pestilos.css y seccionPrueba.css;
en mi archivo 1 (Pestilos.css)  tengo = formulario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2 (seccionPrueba.css) =formulario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ambos archivos se desarrollo en BOOTSTRAP 
cuando quiero a mi primer archivo modificar  el formulario por que cuando modifico un atributo se modifican mis dos archivos!???

en mi index principal tengo 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu pregunta esta muy desordenada y es dificil de entender.  Pero por lo poco que entendi, necesitas selectores css mas especificos.

Comment: ya logre lo que querías agradezco tu comentario ! :)